# The Euler-Poisson equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, calculus-of-variations

$$\int_{0}^\pi (x''^2+4x^2) dt$$
$$ x(0)=x'(0)=0; x(\pi)=0;x'(\pi)=\sinh(\pi)$$
This is The Euler-Poisson equation, i found:
$$\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}-\frac {d}{dt} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x'} +\frac {d^2}{d^2t} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x''}=0$$
$$2x''''=8x$$
$$x''''(t)=4x;$$
decide which way next?
${{{}}}$

Comment: Assuming $x^{(4)} = 4x$ is correct, the way to solve it is to first write down and solve the [characteristic equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_equation_%28calculus%29) of this ODE. This is  $\lambda^4 = 4$ which has the four solutions $\lambda_i = \sqrt{2}, -\sqrt{2}, i\sqrt{2},-i\sqrt{2}$ giving you the solution $x = \sum_{i=1}^4 A_i e^{\lambda_i t}$. Apply BC and simplify.

Comment: btw I get $x^{(4)} + 4x = 0 \implies x^{(4)} = -4x$.

Comment: Yes, u right, i lost -

Comment: $$x(t)=C_1 e^{-t} sin(t)+C_2 e^{t} sin(t)+C_3 e^{-t} cos(t)+C_4 e^{t} cos(t)$$ it's right?

Comment: Yes that seems correct. Now just apply the boundary conditions and you are done (to simpliy the final answer you might want to use $[e^{t} - e^{-t}]/2 = \sinh(t)$).

Comment: i found $$c_1=1/2;c_2=-1/2;c_3=c_4=0;x(t)=-sin(t) sinh(t)$$

Comment: I get the same thing. If you want you can pose an answer to your own question (and you can accept it also).

Answer (score 1):

$$x^{(4)}=-4x$$
$$x(t)=C_1 e^{-t} sin(t)+C_2 e^{t} sin(t)+C_3 e^{-t} cos(t)+C_4 e^{t} cos(t)$$
$$C_1=1/2; C_2=-1/2; C_3=C_4=0$$
$$x(t)=-sin(t) sinh(t)$$